# Find the smallest column number where a substring appears (in a multi-line range)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Range `$A$1:$C$10` with cells that can be empty or that can contain text respecting the following format

1. `string1` (string1 alone)
2. `string1, string2, ...` (`string1` at the begining of a sequence of strings separated with a comma separator)
3. `stringN, ..., string1, ...` (`string1` somewhere in the middle of a sequence)
4. `..., string1` (`string1` at the end of a sequence)

Further, I also have a table "`myTable`" with two columns "`String`" and "`firstOccurence`".

In column "`string`" I have values such as :

```
string1
string2
string3
...
stringN
```

In column "`firstOccurence`" I would like to insert the smallest column number where the string appears (c.f. above formats) in the range `$A$1:$C$10` (multiple lines). I.e. if I have "`string1`" in column "`string`" and "`string1`" is in cells `B2` and `C6` (regardless of the format), I would like to have "`2`" in column "`firstOccurrence`" (B being the 2nd column)

How can I achieve this with an Excel (array) formula ?

So far I have this code :

```
=IF([@[String]]<>"";
    IF(
        OR(
            COUNTIF($A$1:$C$10;[@[String]])>0;
            COUNTIF($A$1:$C$10;[@[String]]&", *")>0;
            COUNTIF($A$1:$C$10;"*, "&[@[String]])>0;
            COUNTIF($A$1:$C$10;"*, "&[@[String]]&", *")>0
        );
        ### What should I put here ? ### ;
        ""
    );
    ""
)
```

Thanks a lots in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this array formula in the [firstOccurence] column of your myTable. As it is an array formula, confirm it with `CTRL+shift+enter`

```
=AGGREGATE(15;6;IF(FIND([@[String]];$A$1:$C$10)>0;COLUMN($A$1:$C$10));1)
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine if ``string1`` is not a substring of ``string2``. Is there a way to improve the formula in order to allow ``string1`` to be a substring of ``string2`` ? Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you try to avoid array formulas at all costs, and you only need to check columns A,B & C, you can use the formula below:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A$10,"*"&$E2&"*")>0,1,
    IF(COUNTIFS(B$1:B$10,"*"&$E2&"*")>0,2,
        IF(COUNTIFS(C$1:C$10,"*"&$E2&"*")>0,3,0)
    )
)
```

This will pick up String1 even if it is a sub string of string 2. It is also case sensitive. But it is fairly easy to alter the formula if you need to.

Here is an image to show it working:

[image]

If you are wondering, the formula to get the column letter is:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(ADDRESS(1,$F2,2),FIND("$",ADDRESS(1,$F2,2))-1),"Not Found")
```

Any follow up questions, let me know and I will do my best to help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I have 40+ columns, and I'm using the result of the function inside an already *long* formula. That's why I was looking for an array formula. I just tried to provide a simplified example illustrating the problem I was facing. Best regards.

Comment: @Kraal No problem. You are correct, if you are dealing with 40+ columns, my answer is not a viable option. The array formula answer was already there, so thought I'd include a non array formula for completeness as it may help others that have similar questions.

Comment: Sure, that's why I marked your answer as useful as it may help other people.